# Selenium Python 3.4.3 Automatic Downloading (Button) Section

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, download

so i am currently struggling to be able to click the "download button". I have tried using the `css_selector` in multiple different ways and the way i am most sure of (below) is giving me an error for some reason. Can someone please have a look at my code below and help me understand what is wrong with the code.

Here is the whole code of the program:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://torrentz.eu/')

searchElem = browser.find_element_by_id('thesearchbox')
searchElem.send_keys('Limitless')
searchButton = browser.find_element_by_id('thesearchbutton')
searchButton.click()


wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 6)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.results dl")))

link_num_1 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.results dl dt a')
link_num_1.click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.download dl")))

link_num_2 = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.download dl dt a')
link_num_2[1].click()
```

This is where the problem is:

```
Site_link_trynum_1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.category-detail li a")))
#Site_link_trynum_1 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.li a")
Site_link_trynum_1.click()
```

Comment: What exactly you want to click on results page?

Comment: @Andersson. What i would like to click on the that page is any of the links that lead to the downloading of the that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it `div.category-detail li a` cannot be found because that page has been opened in a new window, while Selenium is looking for it in the original window (torrents.eu). 
You can try to switch windows using the [switch_to_window()](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames)
 method, all though since you are dealing with a lot of popups, it might be better to fetch the outgoing url and open it in the current window like so,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://torrentz.eu/')

searchElem = browser.find_element_by_id('thesearchbox')
searchElem.send_keys('Limitless')
searchButton = browser.find_element_by_id('thesearchbutton')
searchButton.click()


wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 6)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.results dl")))

link_num_1 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.results dl dt a')
link_num_1.click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.download dl")))

link_num_2 = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.download dl dt a')
link = link_num_2[1].get_attribute("href")
browser.get(link)

Site_link_trynum_1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.category-detail li a.torrent")))
#Site_link_trynum_1 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.li a")
Site_link_trynum_1.click()
```

It might be worth considering though, if fetching links of a site is your aim, to avoid Selenium all together and write a sort of web crawler. If you do move forward with Selenium though, it might be worth to take a look at [Splinter](http://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which is an abstraction layer on top of Selenium, making it easier to write tests. The test above would look something like so when using Splinter,

```
from splinter import Browser

def test_torrents():

    with Browser() as browser:

        browser.visit('https://torrentz.eu/')

        # Search for something
        browser.find_by_id("thesearchbox").fill("Limitless")

        # Hit the search button
        searchButton = browser.find_by_id('thesearchbutton')
        searchButton.click()

        # Get the results and click the first
        results = browser.find_by_css('div.results dl dt a')
        results.first.click()

        # Get the torrents and visit the second (first is sponsored link)
        torrents = browser.find_by_css('div.download dl dt a')
        browser.visit(torrents[1]["href"])

        # Get the file
        torrent_file = browser.find_by_css("div.category-detail li a.torrent")
        print torrent_file["href"]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice on the splinter, but first i have just tried your method on the Selenium one and it is giving me a lot of error. Can you please clarify what `link = link_num_2[1].get_attribute("href")
browser.get(link)` exactly does.

Comment: `link_num_2` contains all the elements found by the css selector `div.download dl dt a`.  From all those elements I address the second element with `link_num_2[1]` because `link_num_2[0]` is a sponsored link. From the second element, an `a` element, I retrieve the attribute `href` as in `<a href="http://link-im-interesting-in">`. `link` will thus be equal to `http://link-im-interesting-in`. `browser.get(link)` will then instruct the current window to navigate to `http://link-im-interesting-in`.

Comment: I see what you are saying but this time it is not giving me any feedback. Meaning there is no error but it seems like the `browser.get(link)` is not going to the link.

Comment: When I add some print statements after each link, I get the folowing : `link_num_1 :  https://torrentz.eu/9ea0c575520a3065d85b285c9474231192368db7`, 
`link :  https://1337x.to/torrent/1525717/Limitless-S01E20-HDTV-x264-LOL-ettv/`, 
`Site_link_trynum_1 :  http://torcache.net/torrent/9EA0C575520A3065D85B285C9474231192368DB7.torrent`. From what I can tell, It does go to the links. The last link just happens to result in a 404.

Comment: Alright, i figured out what was wrong. Thanks for the help.